How can I manage validation logic for 150+ screens with unique business rules across microservices?
Currently, I'm working on an application with a microservice architecture. Each screen may corresponds to a separate microservice, and each screen has its own unique validation logic. Some screens share common validation needs (e.g., mandatory fields, date checks), but the vast majority have very specific, complex rules tailored to the business logic of each screen.
Currently, I attempted to handle this complexity by using SQL scripts for each screen. When a user uploads data (via Excel), the data is processed into CSV and dumped into a temporary table. Then, I execute a series of SQL queries to handle validation and data integrity. These SQL queries perform checks for things like:

Cross-table lookups
Unique constraint checks

For example, a script might check if a "User Code" exists in the relevant table, another might validate that an "Employee Number" is unique, and so on. After the validation, the data is inserted into the main tables if it passes all checks.
This approach works but has become difficult to scale and maintain. We’re now dealing with over 150 screens each requiring different validation logic, and as more screens are added, it’s becoming harder to ensure everything works consistently.
The main problems I’m facing:
Duplication of logic: There’s a lot of repetitive validation code across different screens, even though some of the rules overlap.
Scalability: The approach feels like it’s getting more brittle as the number of screens grows, and more business rules are added.
Maintainability: Making changes to SQL scripts can be risky since I have to carefully place placeholders and other things..
What I’m looking for:
I’m wondering if there’s a better way to manage validation across these screens, especially considering the complexity and the number of different business rules involved. I’ve thought about a few things, like:
Reusable components: Can I generalize validation logic and separate it into reusable components, or should each screen have its own validation class?
Cross-screen validation: How should I handle validations that span multiple screens or microservices, such as ensuring a unique field across multiple services?
My goal is to find a solution that’s scalable and maintainable so that as the system grows or business rules change, I can make updates more easily without worrying about breaking things across different screens.

You wrote "microservices", but it sounds like all the services you have share a common database. Is that correct?

@DocBrown Yes, That's correct.

To double-check terminology, by “screen” do you mean a UI data entry form?

@bob Actually each excel represents screen, for an example let's say there is screen called "User", so there'll be bunch of fields to create an user, in-order to create users in bulk client demanded excel to do that.

Perhaps "fragility" would be a better term than "scalability" for what you are describing?

Ok, you have a system with 150 services and a common, monolithic database. On the web, you will find hot debates if this really counts as a microservice architecture, that the DB is a single point of failure and the system won't scale well.
Still most sources say this architecture is not uncommon. Indeed, there is one point which can be implemented easier with a single database than with a real microservice architecture, and that is strong data consistency. You can achieve this by implementing the validation logic directly in the one common place which you still have available - the database - using central constraints, central triggers and central stored procedures (as opposed to "distributed SQLs which are part of a service"). That resolves the issues "duplication of logic" as well as "cross-screen validation" and "reusability". Of course, simple validation rules like mandatory fields should probably be checked in each service directly, mainly for performance and latency reasons.
The drawback of this approach is that you cannot easily implement the validation rules inside the services in an OO manner. You will have to do this outside, in SQL and the programming language your database offers for stored procedures.
Alternatively, you may introduce extra reusable validation services, apart from your "screen services". That would allow to implement the validation with the same technology/programming language used for all other services.
Of course, the scaling issue won't be solved that way, but that is caused by the monolithic database, not by a decision of where the validation happens. If you want to solve that, you need to rearchitect your system into strongly separated microservices (probably coarser than the mentioned 150 screens), each one with a database on its own (in case it needs one), and allowing a certain amount of eventual consistency between the separated systems. That way,checking certain, complex consistency rules may be deferred until the data is really needed for some use case, and the rules have to be implemented in a service which implements that use case. But that will probably be a lot more effort, maybe not economically feasible.

Well 150 data entry screens, with a large amount of variety, is a very healthy number of screens to be overseeing.
If you've got that far without chaos, then I wouldn't necessarily think that there is any fundamental problem with the current approach.
There isn't necessarily any method of working that will allow you alone to add infinite business rules or cope with unlimited complexity.
It doesn't sound like you actually have "microservices" (i.e. independently operable applications maintained by separate small teams), just a good deal of modularity in the design that you alone are overseeing?
What you'll find as the weight of complexity in the rules starts to creak, is that you probably need to start maintaining design artefacts separate from source code, which represent a certain aspect of the design in a more consolidated or essential form, and then changes proceed first from planning changes to the artefacts, and then second translating the changes to the artefacts into changes in source code.
Developing a useful representation and method of working is something that has to be designed and adapted by you for the specific case.
The problem with this approach of having another layer of planning and representations separate from the source code itself, is that although it's effective in allowing a person to cope with some more complexity reliably, it's extremely hard work in its own right, and the method consumes additional mindspace. Which may be no good for a person who is already struggling for mindspace as well as struggling with the complexity - often complexity becomes a struggle to cope with precisely because someone is spreading themselves too thinly across too many job concerns, not because the complexity of one particular task has become too much to handle even in isolation.
Eventually you'll either find that your plate is simply full and you have to stop adding complexity to the system, or you'll find the need to start adding and organising a larger complement of staff to look after things.
I'd consider whether you've reached that stage where you simply need reinforcement from other people, rather than a crafty method.
